# How to tell SDN switch to process packets directed to him

Tags: python, sdn, openflow, ryu

I'm building a SDN network with Ryu, openVswitch and OpenFlow. 
The problem i'm having is that my datapath doesn't answer messages that are for him, because the table-miss flow entry tells him to flood everything. This happens also for packets of neighbor solicitation, so the host never receives the neighbor advertisement e doesn't know how to speak with the datapath.

How can i tell my datapath to answer this kind of messages? I'm trying to install a new flow entry but i don't know which should be the correct action.

Thank you for your help

Edit:
I'm talking about a general packet, from other hosts of the SDN. The communication between controller and datapath is ok. The problem is that, for example, when datapath receives a neighbor solicitation it doesn't respond, but it sends a packet-in to the controller. I need to know how to make the datapath send the neighbor advertisement.

Comment: You might get a better response on: [http://serverfault.com/](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: thank you, i'll try

Comment: I am not able the understand "datapath doesn't answer messages that are for him". Do you mean that the switch doesn't respond to messages from the controller ? The word "message" is used in the Ryu API to denote communication from controller to switch. Are you talking about this message or a general packet?

Comment: I'm talking about a general packet, from other hosts of the SDN. For example when it receives a neighbor solicitation it doesn't respond to it, but it sends a packet in to the controller.

Comment: What do you mean with "datapath" and "respond" ? A switch (sometimes referred as datapath in general) may forward a packet either to an connected switch/host or controller. If u want to push the packets to another switch/host, use the desired output instruction in your flow with corresponding port, where the target switch is connected. Your packet gets sent to controller, probably with reason NO_MATCH, as the switch cant find a flow to use for forwarding.

Comment: @lunatikz i mean that the host is sending neighbor solicitation and the switch does't send neighbor advertisement back.

Comment: finally i solved with this: when the switch receives a neighbor solicitation it sends it to the controller (this is the default behavior) and the controller builds the neighbor advertisement and tells the switch to send it to the host.